# IndexError: list index out of range- Fill with dummy variable

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 60,000 lists. Each list ranges from 2-5 values.

I need to create a new list with the 3rd value in each of the lists.

The list also needs to remain 60,000 entries long.

If I was doing this with the second value I would do the following:

```
big_list = [['this', 'is', 'a list'], ['list' 'two'], ['here', 'is', 'another one']]

new_list = [value[1] for value in big_list]
```

And `new_list` would be

```
['is', 'two', 'is']
```

In the actual program `new_list` would now be a list of 60,000 values created from the second value in each list. It is important that `new_list` stays the same length.

Now, because some of the lists are only 2 values long if I try

```
new_list = [value[2] for value in big_list]
```

I get a nice `IndexError: list index out of range`

I need the results to be

```
['a list', 'dummy variable', 'another one']
```

Is there any way to preset a dummy variable for the lists that only have 2 values WITHOUT changing anything in `big_list`? The dummy variable can be a random string or a previous value in the list. Please let me know if I'm not being clear & thanks for your help.

Comment: Something like `new_list = [value[2] if len(values) > 2 else 'dummy_variable' for value in big_list]`. Basically if your inner list at time of iteration is of proper length take the stuff you need and if not just return that 'dummy_variable' string

Comment: oops it shoud be `value` not `values`

Comment: That's okay I got it to work, thank you!

Comment: This should be an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)):

```
big_list = [['this', 'is', 'a list'], ['list', 'two'], ['here', 'is', 'another one']]

from itertools import zip_longest

new_list = [value[2] for value in zip(*zip_longest(*big_list, fillvalue='dummy variable'))]
print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```
['a list', 'dummy variable', 'another one']
```

Comment: This is a very clever use of argument unpacking, well done. I'm curious how it compares to just a ternary `if` statement in a list comprehension, though.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy The conditional list comprehension will be faster :)

Comment: Very clever indeed and I think this would be faster than the list comprehension. At least faster than the one I had in the comments